# No number on a partition in server and can't mount

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

On my `parted /dev/sda2` when i use `print free` the output is

```
Partition Table: gpt|

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
        17.4kB  2198GB  2198GB  Free Space
```

there is no number written on it.

and how will i mount it without the number? right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you mount raw partition? You should create filesystem with `mkfs.[fsname]` like `mkfs.xfs` and then **mount filesystem**, not a partition.